# Set Bootstrap Typeahead matcher to case-insensitive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I need to set the matcher in the Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead plug-in to be case-insensitive. The Bootstrap docs specify that a function needs to be passed into the typeahead options, but doesn't specify what that function should be.

I'd be grateful if anyone could tell me how to do this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`matcher` is an option in the parameter for the `typeahead` function. From the documentation:

> The method used to determine if a query matches an item. Accepts a
>   single argument, the item against which to test the query. Access the
>   current query with this.query. Return a boolean true if query is a
>   match.

So, it would look something like this:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    matcher: function(item) {
        // Here, the item variable is the item to check for matching.
        // Use this.query to get the current query.
        // return true to signify that the item was matched.
        return true
    }
})
```

It also says in the documentation that the default behavior for this callback is a `case insensitive` matcher. So, your need should be met out of the box.

Comment: Indeed, it appears that the problem is with the data being parsed before it makes it to the Typeahead matcher, and thus not with typeahead itself.

Comment: Is there a way to make matcher work? I think it is removed in Typeahead.