# How to do Case-Insensitive Search in Typeahead version 0.11.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, typeahead.js

By default search in typeahead is case sensitive.How to change deafult case sensitive search to case in-sensitive ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Bootstrap Typeahead matcher to case-insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815959/set-bootstrap-typeahead-matcher-to-case-insensitive)

Comment: @SandeepJPatel  I have already  checked this not working

Comment: How aobut https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#prefetch 
If You use **transform** on every record so all your names will be unified something like toUpper() or other string method .